# How to solve a system of equations in a field

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

For this question, I am stuck with solving the system of equations in the field. Do I just convert the system into a matrix and then reduce to row echelon form? I am not asking for the  answer, I am just asking if I have the right idea

Show that $Z_7$ is a field and solve the following system of equations in $Z_7$:
$2x + 3y + 2z =1,
3x + 2y + 2z =3,
x + 6y + 6z =0$.

Comment: Yes. I thinks that works just fine. The way the equations are set up though... you should only need to multiply and subtract here and there without a matrix...

Comment: Yes, you do have the right idea. Just keep in mind that you can't divide by any multiple of $7$: they are congruent to $0$.

Comment: Absolutely. Gauß' elimination works in any field

Comment: @Christopher Marley So just use sub and elimination to solve for x y and z?

Comment: Row echelon form is just a way to visualize solving equations by elimination, so yes. @dg123